# Get express js url rout based on id in database

Tags: sql, node.js, sqlite, express, routes

I have sqlite database with article table that contains articleID and articleDescription.

I'm using expressjs as server:

```
app.get('/articleDetail/:id',function(req,res){
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/articleDetail.html'));
var id = req.params.id;
var query = "select * from article where articleID = " + id;

});
```

I want the to show the content of the article based on its id in the database. 
An example: when you select article 5 on the home page, it take you to url ..../articleDetail/5 and the content is shown to the user.

Summary of the 2 questions I have:
How can I connect and id in my database to the id of the url/route?
How can I show the correct article content based on its id using express?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Install module called sqlite3 into your project. It provides exactly what you want, here you can see detailed guide on how to install it and use it for connecting and querying database - http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-nodejs/connect/

Answer (score 0):

So steps should be like this:

1. Get article id from request or url params e.g `let id = req.params.id`
2. Execute query and get the item from database
3. pass the value (article) object to view and render there

   `app.get('/articleDetail/:id',function(req,res){
     var id = req.params.id;
     var query = "select * from article where articleID = " + id;
     // execute the query here 
     res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/articleDetail.html'));
   });`